# How to toggle component in angular in my case?

Tags: javascript, angular, directive

I am trying to find a way to communicate between component in my case.

I have a angular 4 component like this:

my-test.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-test',
    template: `<div>
        <my-child></my-child>
    </div>`
})

export class MyTestComponent{
}
```

my-child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
      <div *ngIf="show" (click)="toggleMe()">Show this</div>`
})

export class MyChildComponent {
   toggleMe() {
       this.show = !this.show;
   }
}
```

I have multiple `my-test` components and every `my-test` component contains one my-child component.

My question is how to make sure there is only one `my-child` component appear at a time. Right now if I click different `my-child` component, they just keep popping up but I only want to have one `my-child` component shown at a time. Is there a quick way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you render `my-test` components? Are they hidden?

Comment: use *ngSwitch ?

Comment: @yurzui my-test is shown by default.

Comment: use ```@Input, @Output``` for passing data into both components and handle with only one boolean value which will be always false but when you click on specific child component that will be true